# Dynamically creating bindings for dynamically created objects during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dynamic

I am trying to create a Datagrid matrix that adds columns with Bindings during runtime.

I'm working in Visual Studio 2019, with C#, WPF and MVVM.

The matrix looks like this:

[image]

The fist three rows are created inside the .xaml of the View, while the last two columns are created dynamically. In another View there's a similar datagrid and each row added there results in a column in this matrix.

The usual columns are created like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding EntryName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

The dynamically added columns are added like this inside of the code behind file of the View:

```
            foreach(IControlRoleViewModel item in vm.ControlRoleTable)
        {
            if (item.EntryName != null) 
            {
                MyGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridCheckBoxColumn { Header = item.EntryName }); 
            }
        }
```

Since the new columns are getting dynamically added I'm not sure how to create dynamic bindings. When I'm using an array I have to define how long it is, and when I tried using a list or an ObservableCollection I failed because of other circumstances.

I need the information of the checkbox in the corresponding row. I already get the information which row is clicked, through the ObservableCollection representing the whole DataGrid.

What I tried was this:

```
            foreach(IControlRoleViewModel item in vm.ControlRoleTable)
        {
            if (item.EntryName != null) 
            {

                _newEntry = item.EntryName + "_IsTrue";

                //send Binding Definition to ViewModel
                vm.newEntry.Add(_newEntry); //vm.newEntry is a List<string> in the ViewModel

                MyGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridCheckBoxColumn { Header = item.EntryName, Binding = new Binding(_newEntry) }); 
            }
        }
```

That way I got the information of the new Binding into the ViewModel. But since the DataGrid representing the whole Matrix is defined like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ProceduresTable }"  SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntryProcedures}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CanUserAddRows="True" IsReadOnly="False" >
```

The Binding could not be found inside of the `ObservableCollection<IProceduresTable> ProceduresTable`.

After that I tried creating a new ObservableCollection inside of the IProceduresTable Interface. But that failed since I couldn't find out how to get a binding into an ObservableCollection that itself is inside an ObservableCollection.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Bindings are dictated by data structures. what is your data structures? show the code, please, "ObservableCollection that itself is inside an ObservableCollection" is not clear enough. `vm` and `ControlRoleTable` - what are they? also: one of the purposes of view model is to provide view with data in convenient format. so "changing view model data structure" is often the easiest solution. transforming data in c# is mcuh simple, when connecting to it in xamol

Comment: Haven't fully analysed but I would point out that when you write "Binding = new Binding(_newEntry)", the _newEntry argument that you are passing is the binding path. However unlike XAML, when done in code there are no assumptions about the source object. You may need to set the Source of the binding.

Answer (score 0):

For such cases I use my GenericRow and GenericTable classes:

You can use these two classes to create dynamic rows and columns. Using GenericRow class, you can generate row with desired property name and you can use the same property name for the columns for suitable binding.

```
public class GenericRow : CustomTypeDescriptor, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region Private Fields
    List<PropertyDescriptor> _property_list = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChange Implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChange Implementation

    #region Public Methods

    public void SetPropertyValue<T>(string propertyName, T propertyValue)
    {
        var properties = this.GetProperties()
                                .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                                .Where(prop => prop.Name.Equals(propertyName));

        if (properties == null || properties.Count() != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("The property doesn't exist.");
        }

        var property = properties.First();
        property.SetValue(this, propertyValue);

        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public T GetPropertyValue<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        var properties = this.GetProperties()
                            .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                            .Where(prop => prop.Name.Equals(propertyName));

        if (properties == null || properties.Count() != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("The property doesn't exist.");
        }

        var property = properties.First();
        return (T)property.GetValue(this);
    }

    public void AddProperty<T, U>(string propertyName) where U : GenericRow
    {
        var customProperty =
                new CustomPropertyDescriptor<T>(
                                        propertyName,
                                        typeof(U));

        _property_list.Add(customProperty);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Overriden Methods

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        var properties = base.GetProperties();
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(
                            properties.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                                      .Concat(_property_list).ToArray());
    }

    #endregion

}
```

and Generic Table:

```
public class GenericTable
{

    private string tableName = "";
    public string TableName
    {
        get { return tableName; }
        set { tableName = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> columnCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> ColumnCollection
    {
        get { return columnCollection; }
        private set { columnCollection = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<GenericRow> genericRowCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<GenericRow> GenericRowCollection
    {
        get { return genericRowCollection; }
        set { genericRowCollection = value; }
    }




    public GenericTable(string tableName)
    {
        this.TableName = tableName;
        ColumnCollection = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();
        GenericRowCollection = new ObservableCollection<GenericRow>(); 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ColumnName is also binding property name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="columnName"></param>
    public void AddColumn(string columnName)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
        column.Header = columnName;
        column.Binding = new Binding(columnName);
        ColumnCollection.Add(column);
    }



    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TableName; 
    }


}
```

And for the XAML side:

```
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid"
              local:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding ColumnCollection}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ...>
```

and finally DataGridColumsBehaior :

```
public class DataGridColumnsBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableColumns",
                                            typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>),
                                            typeof(DataGridColumnsBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableColumnsPropertyChanged));
    private static void BindableColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = source as DataGrid;
        ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> columns = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>;
        dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
        if (columns == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in columns)
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }
        columns.CollectionChanged += (sender, e2) =>
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs ne = e2 as NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs;
            if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Move(ne.OldStartingIndex, ne.NewStartingIndex);
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.OldItems)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Remove(column);
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns[ne.NewStartingIndex] = ne.NewItems[0] as DataGridColumn;
            }
        };
    }
    public static void SetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element, ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(BindableColumnsProperty, value);
    }
    public static ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> GetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)element.GetValue(BindableColumnsProperty);
    }
}
```

In the end, you can create GenericRows and add them into GenericTable. It is like a small viewmodel. In XAML side, dont forget to bind rowscollection as itemsource of the DataGrid.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out!