# Auto Generate Columns of a DataTable from an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am new to WPF and MVVM and have come across this problem.

MapModel:

```
public class MapModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

My data is stored in an ObservableCollection ->

```
private ObservableCollection<MapModel> mapData = new();
public ObservableCollection<MapModel> MapData
{
    get => mapData;
    set
    {
         SetProperty(ref mapData, value);
    }
}
```

The data is taken from a REST API and is set in the `OnNavigatedTo` method. All correctly.

I have a `DataTable` which I want to bind to the `ObservableCollection` and display it in the View as `DataView`.

```
private DataTable mapDataTable = new();
private DataView mapDataView;
public DataTable MapDataTable
{
      get => mapDataTable;
      set
      {
           SetProperty(ref mapDataTable, value);
           MapDataView = mapDataTable.DefaultView;
           MapDataView.RowFilter = $"Name LIKE '%{FilterName}%'";
      }
}

public DataView MapDataView
{
     get => mapDataView;
     set => SetProperty(ref mapDataView, value);
}
```

The reason I want to use a `DataTable` and `DataView` is that I want to add dynamically columns when a check box is checked. Therefore, I have set the `AutoGenerateColumns=true` in the View and `ItemsSource={Binding MapDataView}`.

How can I bind the observable collection to the data table when auto generating the columns? And when I add a column to the data table or filter it, will it automatically update in the View?

Here's everything I want to do. I have added the most important properties from the MapModel in the question. This `ObservableCollection<MapModel>` is a representation of the data behind one let's call it Family (not a very good example but still). I have a multiselect dropdown menu above the DataGrid with numbers from 1 to 5 - Family 1, Family 2, etc. When I select a value from the menu, I want to add a column, called Value 2, which takes the data from REST API for Family 2 and add only the value (not the name, as the names are the same) to the DataTable.

Comment: There is nothing like auto-conversion. You are the only one that knows how a data object can be presented in a table data structure. The question is if it makes sense to "transport" the data as plain data object between Model to View Model or if you should use a DataTable all the way. It really depends on how you have designed your data objects, but if you have followed the most intuitive approach where a property maps to a column, you will get in trouble when adding columns to the DataTable, which youhave to convert back to a plain data object later (to update te Model).

Comment: Note that DataGrid knows how to get the DataView from a DataTable. This means you can bind the ItemsSource directly to the DataTable property.

Comment: Also, the DataTable does not implement any change notification to trigger the binding to update the Binding.Target. You would have to reassign an instance to the DataTable property when the table data has changed.

Comment: Here's everything I want to do. I have added the most important properties from the `MapModel` in the question. This `ObservableCollection<MapModel>` is a representation of the data behind one let's call it Family (not a very good example but still). I have a multiselect dropdown menu above the DataGrid with numbers from 1 to 5 - Family 1, Family 2, etc. When I select a value from the menu, I want to add a column, called Value 2, which takes the data from REST API for Family 2 and add only the value (not the name, as the names are the same) to the DataTable.

Comment: How it should look in the beginning:                                                                        Name | Value 1
Avory | 12                                                                                                                             How it should look after selecting `2` from the dropdown menu:                                Name | Value 1 | Value 2
Avory | 12         | 14
Of course, there are more records, but that is not the point. Do you think that `DataTable` is the right container for this?

Comment: Now that you have updated your question: if MapModel is meant to represent a column then the collection of MapModel items would represent a row. In this case your source collection must be a collection of MapModel collections List<List<MapModel>>. Using an ObservableCollection is redundant here as long as no other type thsn the Binding.Target is observing it - it is not used as binding source.

Comment: DataTable is the right structure if you want to handle data column/row based.

Comment: Every property of the `MapModel` is meant to represent a column in my case. I want to auto generate the columns of the `DataTable` and if another "Family" is selected after starting the program, I want to add a new column to the `DataTable` where I will display only the `Value` property of that "Family". That is all.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand column vs row based. When the value of MapModel.Name represents a column's name: if you have many items where MapModel.Name has the same value (hence they map to the same column) then DataTable is for you but your source collection is of the wrong type (must be a nested list). If your MapModel.Name values are "unique" then you need a row based presentation like a ListBox that present key-value pairs - Name and value are presnted in one row. It'S not clear to me what of both versions you really want.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you!

Comment: you can check this approach for your case : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59411786/3873053